# Returning image buffer results in empty response

Tags: javascript, node.js, image, express

I have a basic node server setup using express, one of my routes is setup to receive, through query params, the url of an image, it's desired size and output format (height and output format are optional). The image is formatted, returns a base64 string which I then convert to a buffer. When I try to return that buffer to the client it just sends an empty response. I can see a 200 response code, the correct content-type and content-length but the response is completely empty.

I've tried switching between res.send(), res.end() and res.write() with no success. I have written the buffer to a file to confirm that it's not corrupt data, the file write is successful and the image data is correct.

```
app.get('/imageprocessor/resize', async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const { url, width, height, outputFormat } = req.query;
    if (!url || !width) {
      return res.status(400).send({
        type: 'Invalid request',
        message: 'You are missing one or more the required query params',
      });
    }
    const imageData = await resizeHelper(url, width, height, outputFormat);
    const imgBuffer = Buffer.from(imageData, 'base64');
    res.type(`image/${outputFormat || 'jpeg'}`).send(imgBuffer);
  } catch (err) {
    console.log('--ERROR--');
    console.log(err);
    return res.status(err.statusCode || 500).send('Could not process image');
  }
});
```

I'd expect the response to allow me to just paste a url like:

[http://localhost:3000/imageprocessor/resize?url=https://www.yosemite.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/04/El-Capitan-*Yosemite-Mariposa-Slide*-Photo-by-Chris-Migeon-700x425.jpg&width=350](http://localhost:3000/imageprocessor/resize?url=https://www.yosemite.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/04/El-Capitan-_Yosemite-Mariposa-Slide_-Photo-by-Chris-Migeon-700x425.jpg&width=350)

into my browser and it should return a resized image. The idea is to be able to use this url in the src attribute of  tags.

Comment: what do you see in the network tab of your devtools in your browser? Or, what do you see if you use `curl` or `wget` to fetch the image?

Comment: @O.Jones Looking in devtools in my browser, the network tab shows the 200 response but of type document, however, when I inspect that request it shows. Content-Type: image/jpeg as expected and a Content-Length: 158697.

I see no image in the response though and if I run the request through Postman it returns with "Could not get any response"